# Mysql search for string and number using MATCH() AGAINST()

Tags: mysql, search, numbers, match-against

I have a problem with the MATCH AGAINST function.

The following query give me the same result:

```
SELECT * FROM models MATCH(name) AGAINST('Fiat 500')
SELECT * FROM models MATCH(name) AGAINST('Fiat')
```

How can I search for both strings and numbers in a column of a FULL TEXT table?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If you need `Fiat` and `500` anywhere where order does not matter, then

```
SELECT * FROM models MATCH(name) AGAINST('+Fiat +500');
```

If you need `Fiat 500` together, then

```
SELECT * FROM models MATCH(name) AGAINST('+"Fiat 500"');
```

If you need `Fiat` and zero or more `500`, then

```
SELECT * FROM models MATCH(name) AGAINST('+Fiat 500');
```

If you need `500` and zero or more `Fiat`, then

```
SELECT * FROM models MATCH(name) AGAINST('Fiat +500');
```

Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-01-28 18:28 EDT

Here are the default settings for FULLTEXT searching

```
mysql> show variables like 'ft%';
+--------------------------+----------------+
| Variable_name            | Value          |
+--------------------------+----------------+
| ft_boolean_syntax        | + -><()~*:""&| |
| ft_max_word_len          | 84             |
| ft_min_word_len          | 4              |
| ft_query_expansion_limit | 20             |
| ft_stopword_file         | (built-in)     |
+--------------------------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Notice that [**ft_min_word_len**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) is 4 by default. The token 500 is length 3. thus it will not be indexed at all. You will have to do three(3) things:

## STEP 01 : Configure for smaller string tokens

Add this to `/etc/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len = 1
```

## STEP 02 : Restart mysql

```
service mysql restart
```

## STEP 03 : Reindex all indexes in the `models` table

You could just drop and add the FULLTEXT index

or do it in stages and see how big it will get in advance

```
CREATE TABLE models_new LIKE models;
ALTER TABLE models_new DROP INDEX name;
ALTER TABLE models_new ADD FULLTEXT name (name);
ALTER TABLE models_new DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO models_new SELECT * FROM models;
ALTER TABLE models_new ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE models RENAME models_old;
ALTER TABLE models_new RENAME models;
```

When you are satisfied this worked, then run

```
DROP TABLE models_old;
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: If I search only for "500" give me no result...why?

Comment: not trying to hijack but @RolandoMySQLDBA where do you place the + sign when using a php var? `"+'FIAT 500'"`

Comment: @DannyG you got the quotes backwards. Use `('+"FAIT 500"')`

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I have tried all of the above steps and still having issues with 2 character words. I have posted a question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28278288/mysql-fulltext-search-using-2-character-word

Comment: Is it possible to give more parameters to against() like for example: AGAINST('Fiat', 'Benz') ?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case it helps others, if you're using InnoDB you need to use a different set of mysql.cnf properties

eg

```
show variables like 'innodb_ft%';
```

and in my.cnf set the following value instead of ft_min_word_len

```
innodb_ft_min_token_size=1
```