# Mysql 'match against' with multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, string-matching

How to compare records from one column with 'match against'? That code is not working properly:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE MATCH (`content` WHERE `id` != \'\')AGAINST (`content` WHERE `id` = \'\' IN BOOLEAN MODE)'; 
$p = $db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your question to explain what are you are trying to achieve. Your current query makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match), the `MATCH()` syntax is like this:

```
MATCH (col1,col2,...) AGAINST (expr [search_modifier])
```

And is described as:

> MATCH() takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be searched. AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional modifier that indicates what type of search to perform. The search string must be a string value that is constant during query evaluation. This rules out, for example, a table column because that can differ for each row.

So, the syntax you have used is completely invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're asking for. Someone else has provided a pretty good response to a similar question posted in the following link:

[Mysql search for string and number using MATCH() AGAINST()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572375/mysql-search-for-string-and-number-using-match-against)

Again it seems to me that you are trying to match patterns/expressions between 2 columns from 2 different tables, if I have understood your example correctly. If so, then maybe the solution provided in the link isn't 'the way to go'. It's up to you, hope it helps..