# MySql Fulltext search using 2 character word

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I've set `ft_min_word_len = 1` and running `show variables like 'ft%';` also shows the same.
Also have already updated the Fulltext indexes by dropping and re-creating them.

But when I run `SELECT OriginalProductName FROM products WHERE MATCH (ProductName) AGAINST ('+samsung +tv' IN BOOLEAN MODE);` against a row which is having "Samsung Hg55nc890xf 3d 1080p Led lcd Tv Hdtv" as value it returns 0 results.

It works as expected when I execute `SELECT OriginalProductName FROM products WHERE MATCH (ProductName) AGAINST ('+samsung +led' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

I am using MySQL 5.6.22. Innodb is the Table engine.

How can make MySql Fulltext search to search 2 character words like tv, 32, US etc...?

Comment: I also have 5.6.22 and smaller then 3 values of ft_min_word_len does not work. I mean I can also see the value is set to 2 in show variables and I rebuild the index, but it does not take into effect. The shortest string I can find with the fulltext index is still 3 characters long.

Comment: The closest solution I've found is `SELECT  ProductName FROM products WHERE ProductName LIKE '%tv%' AND MATCH (ProductName) AGAINST ('+samsung' IN BOOLEAN MODE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this issue was specific to `innodb` storage engine. I've solved the issue by adding
`[mysqld]
innodb_ft_min_token_size =2;` to `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: hello how do i find "/etc/my.cnf" in my windows 7